# Bootstrap slider does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I use `Angular.js` and `Bootstrap` to build my application. A directive inserts an input tag to DOM. I want to use `slider` on the input tag to modify it. I followed the [tutorial](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/).

```
tag = '<input type="text" class="slider" ng-model="costPerDay"/>';
// pass it to a template and push to DOM
$('.slider').slider({       
  max: 500,                  
  orientation: 'horizontal',
  selection: 'after'        
});
```

The `slider` function exists on the jQuery object, but invoking it has no effect, without any exceptions! My input is still just an `<input>` tag.

What is wrong in my code? What is not taken into account? Something bugs or dependencies?

Comment: you need to write a directive for this

Comment: you mean jqueryui slider right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your JavaScript code running inside a [document ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)? It may be that the JS is executing before the DOM is finished loading, and therefore it doesn't find your `.slider` element. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider').slider({       
      max: 500,                  
      orientation: 'horizontal',
      selection: 'after'        
    });
})
```

Comment: If the input '.slider' isn't into the DOM when the page is loading, the code `$('.slider').slider({ ... })` won't do anything; cause it's interpreted after the page load. He must declare the slider after adding the input element.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the initialization code in a directive.

Here's a prototype I did for bxSlider:
http://jsfiddle.net/vibhor/3GFWS/

```
myApp.directive('slideit', function () {
    return function (scope, elm, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.slideit, function (images) {
            var html = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                html += '<li><img src="' + images[i].src + '" alt="" /></li>';
            }
            $("#" + $(elm[0]).attr('id')).html(html).bxSlider({
                adaptiveHeight: true,
                mode: 'fade'
            });
        });
    };
});
```

It was a bit complicated so had to create the DOM manually.

You can put your html code in a partial and refer to it in the directive. The reference to the DOM created by the directive would be available in the elm variable. If you call .slider() on it, it should do the job.